# How to find out employees having same department but different shifts

Tags: sql, informix

I have a table employee which has different attributes like emp_code, naeme,...., deptt.
There is another table called nightShift which has fields- emp_code, shift_time.
Any employee which is not in nightShift table is automatically assumed to be in day shift.

Now I have to find out those deptt which has some employees working in night shift and some in normal shift
What can be a query for this.

Example

```
**Employees**
----------------------------------------
emp_code|  Name     |   deptt
----------------------------------------
e1         John     Ops
e2        Martin        Ops
e3        Gary      Infra
e4        John                  Facilities
e5        Michael       Ops
e6        Alan      Ops
e7        Tony      Facilites
e8        Alex      Infra
e9        Peter     Infra
e10       Ron                Ops





**nightShift**    
----------------------------------------
emp_code       |    shift_time  
----------------------------------------
e1          shiftA
e2          shiftA
e5          shiftB
e4          shiftB
e7          shiftC
```

Now in the output, I want only Deptt Ops, as some of its employees are in night shift(e1,e2,e5) and some in normal shift(e6,e10)
The output should NOT contain Infra  as all employees(e3,e8,e9) are in normal shift and none in night shift.
The output should NOT contain Facilities  as all employees(e4,e7) are in night shift and none in normal shift.

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a group by version - join both tables in a left join and count nightShifts per department. If count is greater than zero but not equal to count of all workers in department, we have a match.

```
select employees.deptt
from employees
left join nightShift
  on employees.emp_code = nightShift.emp_code
group by employees.deptt
having count (nightShift.emp_code) > 0
   and count (employees.emp_code) <> count (nightShift.emp_code)
```

[Test it on Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/841a9/1).

Comment: Suppose a department had 4 employees, and 2 were on day shift and 2 on night shift.  You wouldn't select that department because the two counts in the second HAVING clause condition would be equal.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Not true. count (employees.emp_code) returns total count of employees in department regardless of shift they work in.

Comment: OK - it must be past my bedtime or something.  My mistake.

Comment: @Nikola,Jonathan Did not get time to test these yet. But still, many many thanksfor putting your precious time in it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along these lines

```
select 
  distinct e.deptt
from
  Employees e
inner join
  NightShift n
on 
  n.emp_code = e.emp_code
Where
  e.deptt not in ('Facilities', 'Facilites')
```

The inner join will eliminate everyone not working night shifts, then in the where we find any results not working in deptt Facilities

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to count the number of night shift workers for each department, and the number of day shift workers for each department, and you're concerned with those departments where both counts are bigger than zero.

Stage 1: Night shift workers per department:

```
SELECT e.deptt, COUNT(*) AS headcount
  FROM Employees  AS e
  JOIN NightShift AS n
    ON n.emp_code = e.emp_code
 GROUP BY e.deptt
```

Stage 2: Day shift workers per department

There are various possible strategies for this.  One is to count the total workers for each department and subtract the number of nightshift workers:

```
SELECT d.deptt, (d.headcount - n.headcount) AS headcount
  FROM (SELECT e2.deptt, COUNT(*) AS headcount
          FROM Employees AS e2
         GROUP BY e2.deptt
       ) AS d
  JOIN (SELECT e.deptt, COUNT(*) AS headcount
          FROM Employees  AS e
          JOIN NightShift AS n
            ON n.emp_code = e.emp_code
         GROUP BY e.deptt
       ) AS n
    ON d.deptt = e.deptt
```

Stage 3: Pick those departments where the headcounts on the dayshift and night shift are both non-zero:

```
SELECT d.deptt, (d.headcount - n.headcount) AS dayshift, n.headcount AS nightshift
  FROM (SELECT e2.deptt, COUNT(*) AS headcount
          FROM Employees AS e2
         GROUP BY e2.deptt
       ) AS d
  JOIN (SELECT e.deptt, COUNT(*) AS headcount
          FROM Employees  AS e
          JOIN NightShift AS n
            ON n.emp_code = e.emp_code
         GROUP BY e.deptt
       ) AS n
    ON d.deptt = e.deptt
 WHERE d.headcount > 0
   AND n.headcount > 0
```

There might be a more succinct formulation, but I'm fairly sure this would give the correct answer.

Subject to the note that this has not been anywhere near an actual SQL DBMS so there could be some syntax errors in it.

I'm also assuming you're using a supported version of Informix (and not Informix OnLine or Informix SE).  Some older versions of Informix would not support all this syntax but I believe all the 11.x versions (which are all currently supported) should all handle these queries.

You can probably simplify this along the lines of [Nikola Markovinović](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1231866/nikola-markovinovic)'s answer.